# android fcm notification not received

Tags: java, android

android fcm notification not received and while the device which supposed to receivethe notification shows this message in Logcat (Received from FCM TITLE: null, Received from FCM BODY: null). I have already checked that notification is not being received in both <26 and >26 SDK Versions

====================MyFirebaseMessagingService===============================

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String channel_id = "the_id";


@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
    updateTokenToFirebase(s);

}


private void updateTokenToFirebase(String token) {
    IDrinkShopAPI mService = Common.getAPI();

    mService.updateToken("SERVER_01",token,"0")
            .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG_TOKEN",response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG_TOKEN",t.getMessage());
                }
            });


}



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            sendNotification26(remoteMessage);
        else
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);

    }

}

private void sendNotification26(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    String title = data.get("title");
    String message = data.get("message");



    NotificationHelper helper ;
    Notification.Builder builder;
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    helper = new NotificationHelper(this);

    builder = helper.getDrinkShopNotification(title,message,defaultSoundUri);

    helper.getManager().notify(new Random().nextInt(),builder.build());


}


private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

   String title = data.get("title");
   String message = data.get("message");



    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager mn =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mn.notify(new Random().nextInt(),builder.build());

   }
}
```

=========================NotificationHelper =================================

```
//this class is used to implement notification for all android versions

public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "the_id";
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Drink_Shop";

private NotificationManager notificationManager;

public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        createChannel();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createChannel() {

    NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

    nc.enableLights(false);
    nc.enableVibration(true);
    nc.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    getManager().createNotificationChannel(nc);

}

public NotificationManager getManager() {

    if(notificationManager == null)

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    return notificationManager;

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public Notification.Builder getDrinkShopNotification(String title,
                                                     String message,
                                                     Uri soundUri)
{

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .setAutoCancel(true);




   }


}
```

=============================Manifest=======================================

```
  <service
        android:name=".Services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

============================Build.gradle====================================

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

===========================IFCMService=======================================

```
 public interface IFCMService {

@Headers({
        "Content-Type:application/json",
        "Authorization:mytoken"
})
 @POST("fcm/send")
 Call<MyResponse> sendNotification(@Body DataMessage body);

}
```

==========================sendNotificationToServer===============================

// this method used to send the notification to server device

```
  private void sendNotificationToServer(OrderResult orderResult) {

    mService.getToken("SERVER_01", "1")
            .enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {

                    Map<String,String> contentSend = new HashMap<>();
                    contentSend.put("title","NEW ORDER");
                    contentSend.put("message","You have got new order" + orderResult.getOrderId());

                    DataMessage dataMessage = new DataMessage();
                    if(response.body().getToken() != null)
                        dataMessage.setTo(response.body().getToken());

                        dataMessage.setData(contentSend);

                        IFCMService ifcmService = Common.getFCMService();
                         ifcmService.sendNotification(dataMessage)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

                                    if(response.code() == 200){

                                        if(response.body().success == 1){

                                     Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this,
                                     getResources().getString(R.string.order_submitted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                            //Clear Carts From Room Database
                                            Common.cartRepository.emptyCart();
                                            //finish();
                                        }
                                        else {

                                            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Send Notification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });



 }
```

Comment: Have u tried receiving notification, while app is running in background?

Comment: why what is the difference bro?!

Comment: you need to build() too notification, but i can't see .build() in your code.

Comment: here bro i use helper class      helper.getManager().notify(new Random().nextInt(),builder.build());

Comment: as you saying null message is showing in logcat which means, you are receiving it but not building notification properly and passing parameters correctly while pushing it, try to check it when app is running in background.

Comment: i have tried to check it when app is running in background and same message show up

Comment: message, where?

Comment: Logcat sill showing Received from FCM TITLE: null
    Received from FCM BODY: null

Comment: i have used okhttp method to push notifications, so not much familiar with your method of pushing notification to server, but try to use jsonObject instead of map.

Comment: can u please show me how to implement json object as example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202378/discussion-between-haider-saleem-and-alazar-komar).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by downgrading firebase-messaging library as follow (implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4') as will as .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)) in NotificationCompat. However this has solved the issue for me for SDK version lower than 26. Anyone knows why it is still cashing on APIs higher than 26 ?! help me please

Answer (score -1):

When the App is running in background the notification is received in the system tray, and when is tapped, the intent is sended to your activity default, with the notification with payload of content of it.

When your application is running in front, the notification is received with the FirebaseMessagingService and the logic that you overrided.

I think you should add the logic of the first point, when the app is running in background

Check here more information

[Handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)